# How to get Arrow marks instead of bullets in html menus

Tags: asp.net, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

My HTML code in **.cshtml** page is

```
 <menu id="menuTools">
        @Html.ActionLink("Test1", "Index", new { Area = "Tools", Controller = "Controller1" })
        @Html.ActionLink("Test2", "Index", new { Area = "Tools", Controller = "Controller2" })
        @Html.ActionLink("Test3", "Index", new { Area = "Tools", Controller = "Controller3" })
    </menu>
```

I need to have arrow marks instead of bullets in front of each menu. Thanks.

Update: When I click the particular menu, I need to have the arrow mark. Thanks.

Comment: You are generating action links and when you click won't you get redirected to those urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this may be helpful: http://www.chami.com/tips/internet/050798i.html
so "→" is a "&" + "rarr;"

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to give the ul just a style like

```
list-style-image:url('/path/to/yourArrow.png');
```

Then you may will have to use a
    list-style-position: Xpx Ypx;
additionally to allign it right. See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-image.asp

Answer (score 1):

If you are using list `<li>`, there is an option in CSS to set custom image as bullet image. You may do that using `list-style-image:`

Comment: only when clicking particular menu, I need to display corresponding arrow. How it is possible. Thanks